# Accessing other HDDs ubuntu server CLI

Tags: partitioning, mount

This is quite possibly the most basic question ever asked on this forum, but I can't find an answer anywhere. I have installed Ubuntu Server on a HDD and installed two additional HDDs for file storage. The installation went fine and adding the other two HDDs went flawlessly.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.1 GB, 250059350016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30401 cylinders, total 488397168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e69a4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          501758   488396799   243947521    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760   488396799   243947520   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 765633 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xe2b08df4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdc: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
81 heads, 63 sectors/track, 765633 cylinders, total 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x147347c4

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1            2048  3907029167  1953513560   83  Linux

Disk /dev/mapper/Movieland--vg-root: 245.6 GB, 245631025152 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 29862 cylinders, total 479748096 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/Movieland--vg-root doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/Movieland--vg-swap_1: 4169 MB, 4169138176 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 506 cylinders, total 8142848 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/Movieland--vg-swap_1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

The two 2TB drives have been mounted to /media/primarydrive and /media/backupdrive.

/dev/mapper/Movieland--vg-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/primarydrive type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sdc1 on /media/backupdrive type ext4 (rw)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
```

Now for the question, how do I actually access these drives to put files on them?

I would like to put movies into /media/primarydrive/movies, but when I create the directory and then try to access it, I am told No such file or directory. What do I need to do to use these drives? Sorry for the wall of text, but in my research these are the answers to the two most common responses on these forums. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the drives are mounted, can you change directory to them ?

```
cd /media/primarydrive
```

If you can, can you make a folder on them ?

```
mkdir mymovies
```

(Or `mkdir /media/primarydrive/mymovies` from any other location)

Can you post the contents of the file `/etc/fstab`, that will tell us what drives are mounted, how they are mounted and where they are mounted to.

Comment: /dev/mapper/Movieland--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=a4ff0af5-68fa-4ff2-9417-7d700096310a /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/Movieland--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
# Everything after has been added on 12MAR14 by Conor in an attempt to get the 2x2TB drives mounted
/dev/sdb1 /media/primarydrive ext4 defaults 0 0
/dev/sdc1 /media/backupdrive ext4 defaults 0 0

Comment: I cannot change directory to them or create other files/folders on them.

Comment: I don't think you have mounted them correct. Comment out, or remove, your own entries from fstab and reboot. Then manually mount one of your drives with mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt then try and copy a file to /mnt . or, after the reboot, use your file manager go to filesystem and click your drive.

Comment: Ok, I can now change directories into /mnt...what am I doing wrong with the way I was doing it before?

Comment: I don't think you mounted the drive with r,w attributes. To be honest, you would be just as wise to use your file manager and click the hard disk to mount and open it. I find disks a bit easier to manage that way. Do you really need to auto mount them at boot time ?

Comment: In fact I've just re read..... Does the directory /media/primary drive exist ? It has to exist in order for the disk to be mounted to it.

Comment: I don't know if NEED is the right word, but I would like it to be as carefree as possible once I get it all up and running. So when the power goes out and comes back on, I don't spend an hour trying to figure out why I can't access any of my movies. :)

Comment: When I go into the media folder and type ls "primary drive" and "backup drive" are both listed and now that I have manually mounted sdb1, I can access /media/primarydrive, so now I am really confused.

Comment: Understood. Does the directory /media/primary drive exist ? It has to exist for a disk to be mounted to it.

Comment: I can also access /media/backupdrive which is even weirder because that  HDD isn't even mounted

Comment: You can probably access the /media/primary drive folder because it is now not have a disk mounted to it. Create a folder in your home directory called disk1, edit your fstab to mount your disk there. /media/primary drive and /media/backup drive are folders remember. You mount a disk to a folder. Then, when yo look inside the folder you are being redirected to the disk.

Comment: wtf, that worked. So why won't it work with /media/primarydrive?

Comment: I think its to do with the permissions of /media. Always better to just use your /home directory.

Comment: Weird, thank you. You just saved my computer from going out the window.

Comment: Welcome. It actually makes sense, I don't think normal users have full write access to /media. Don't forget to mark my answer as correct lol